# Postal code null always with GeoCode

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm trying Geocoding to get postalCode from Latitude and Longitude but it always returns NULL, is there any way to get it free or i'm doing it the wrong way with Geocode?

Here's code::

```
         Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(context,
                Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> add;

        try {
            Double mLattitude   =   Double.parseDouble(mLatt);
            Double mLongitude   =   Double.parseDouble(mLong);
            add = geo.getFromLocation(mLattitude, mLongitude, 1);
            if (add != null && !add.isEmpty()) {
                int size    =   add.size();
                Log.e(" init Geo "," List address size "+size);
                Log.e(" initGeo ","Add json "+add);
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                if (geo.isPresent()) {
                    Address returnAddress = add.get(0);
                    if(returnAddress!=null) {
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();
                        str.append(zipcode + "");
                    }else
                    {
                        return thirdPartyService();
                    }

                    if (str == null || str.toString().isEmpty() || str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                       return thirdPartyService();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e(" ", "GEO CODE PRESENT");
                        return str.toString();
                    }


                } else {
                    Log.e(" ", "GEO CODE NOT PRESENT");
                    return thirdPartyService();
                }

            }else
            {
                Log.e(" ", "GEO CODE NOT PRESENT");
                return thirdPartyService();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }


09-08 11:37:42.044    32723-640/? E/init Geo﹕ List address size 1
09-08 11:37:42.044    32723-640/? E/initGeo﹕ Add json [Address[addressLines=[0:"93, Delhi - Jaipur Expy",1:"Sector 32",2:"Gurgaon, Haryana 122001",3:"India"],feature=93,admin=Haryana,sub-admin=null,locality=Gurgaon,thoroughfare=Delhi - Jaipur Expy,postalCode=null,countryCode=IN,countryName=India,hasLatitude=true,latitude=28.448048,hasLongitude=true,longitude=77.040622,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]
```

Comment: I am facing same issue with android version 5.0 though its working fine in 6.0 and 7.0. Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode()), Geocoding returns the postal code of the `address or null` if it is unknown.

Your code implementation is right.

As When I test with (37.22,33.22) it returns null .

But when I use (28.6100, 77.2300) then it return 110001

So you have put some check while displaying in your app

Answer (score 0):

try with below code.

```
private void getLocationAddress(final double latitude, final double longitude){    
     Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                        String result = null;
                        try {
                            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                                    latitude, longitude, 1);
                            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                                }
                                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                                result = sb.toString();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
                        }
    }
```

Use the following permission too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Postal code is not null always with Geocoding, it depends at place. Try some places at the city and you would likely get it, and it is problem to get it at countryside. So if your app needs it just treat at as possible `null` value